# NodeJs define global constants

Tags: javascript, node.js, constants

im wondering how to define global constants in node js.

My approach so far:

constants.js:

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
MY_CONST: 'const one'});
```

controller.js:

```
var const = require(./common/constants/constants.js);
console.log(const.MY_CONST) ==> const one
const.MY_CONST ='something'
console.log(const.MY_CONST) ==> const one
```

Ok thats fine so far. But then i wanted to structure my constants like this:

constants.js:

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    MY_TOPIC: {
        MY_CONST: 'const one'
    }
});
```

controller.js:

```
var const = require(./common/constants/constants.js);
console.log(const.MY_TOPIC.MY_CONST) ==> const one
const.MY_TOPIC.MY_CONST ='something'
console.log(const.MY_TOPIC.MY_CONST) ==> something
```

Hmm no MY_CONST is not constant any more...
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: `const` is not a valid variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to freeze inner object too. Something like that

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    MY_TOPIC: Object.freeze({
        MY_CONST: 'const one'
    })
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var consts = Object.freeze({
  MY_TOPIC: Object.freeze({
    MY_CONST: 'const one'
  })
});

console.log(consts.MY_TOPIC.MY_CONST);
consts.MY_TOPIC.MY_CONST = "something";
console.log(consts.MY_TOPIC.MY_CONST);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can nest your `freeze` calls, but I think what you actually want is

```
// constants.js
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    MY_CONST: 'const one'
});
```

```
// controller.js
const MY_TOPIC = require(./common/constants/constants.js);
console.log(MY_TOPIC.MY_CONST) // ==> const one
MY_TOPIC.MY_CONST = 'something'; // Error
console.log(MY_TOPIC.MY_CONST) // ==> const one
```

Answer (score 0):

Object values of the frozen object can be changed.
Read the following example from the [`Object.freeze()` doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to freeze all your object:

> ```
> obj1 = {
>   internal: {}
> };
>
> Object.freeze(obj1);
> obj1.internal.a = 'aValue';
>
> obj1.internal.a // 'aValue'
>
> // To make obj fully immutable, freeze each object in obj.
> // To do so, we use this function.
> function deepFreeze(obj) {
>
>   // Retrieve the property names defined on obj
>   var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
>
>   // Freeze properties before freezing self
>   propNames.forEach(function(name) {
>     var prop = obj[name];
>
>     // Freeze prop if it is an object
>     if (typeof prop == 'object' && prop !== null)
>       deepFreeze(prop);
>   });
>
>   // Freeze self (no-op if already frozen)
>   return Object.freeze(obj);
> }
>
> obj2 = {
>   internal: {}
> };
>
> deepFreeze(obj2);
> obj2.internal.a = 'anotherValue';
> obj2.internal.a; // undefined
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by "*from the Object.freeze() doc*"? If that example is copied from some documentation, you should blockquote it and link the source.

Comment: yes, here is the doc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze